# How to ensure next to `@` should have only alphabets using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing a regexp validation for email. works fine but it allows the user to add the `@.xyz.com`, but it is meaning less. how can i insure that, the user should only add the `alphabet` next to `@` symbol?

in the pattern i have added `[\w\.]` for the reason to add after `@` is `@some.xx.com` purpose. ( user can enter . after/inside alphabet )

```js
$(function(){
 
 $('#email').on('keyup', function(event){
   
   var email = event.target.value;
   var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z]{3,})+@[\w\.]+\.(com|org)$/
   if(!email) return false;
   
   console.log(pattern.test(email));
   
 })
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
```

any one help me?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/6299857

Comment: Why not input type with `email`?

Comment: I'm wondering about the `([a-zA-Z]{3,})+`, is there a reason for the double repetition, or might you just use `[a-z]{3,}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because what follows the `@` must be a word character, just add a word boundary after the `@` with `\b`. Also note that `.` does not need to be escaped in a character set, and you can use the `i` (case insensitive) flag so as not to have to repeat `[a-zA-Z]`:

```js
$('#email').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var email = event.target.value;
  var pattern = /^([a-z]{3,})+@\b[\w.]+\.(?:com|org)$/i
  if (!email) return false;

  console.log(pattern.test(email));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
```

If you additionally want to make sure that `.`s in the input aren't right next to each other, then repeat `(?:\w+\.)` instead of the character set:

```js
$('#email').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var email = event.target.value;
  var pattern = /^([a-z]{3,})+@(?:\w+\.)+(?:com|org)$/i
  if (!email) return false;

  console.log(pattern.test(email));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
```

Comment: why do  you add `?:` mark inside the `or` operator?, even without it works

Comment: Capturing groups should be used for when you need to use the captured group later - such as when trying to match only part of a string, or when you want to be able to backreference the group later in the pattern. If one isn't doing that, best to use a non-capturing group instead, with `(?:` rather than `(`, (could do the same with the initial group, though I'm not sure of its purpose, you might just remove that group entirely)

Comment: How could you manage this @CertainPerformance? Just outstanding!

Comment: This will produce a false positive for strings like `'aaa@a..xyz.com'`

Comment: @3gwebtrain eg if I'm reading code and I see a pattern with a group `(`, that makes me think "This group is being captured, I need to keep in mind that it may be used later", whereas `(?:` instead would make it clear that the group only exists to enable alternation inside it (or to repeat the pattern inside, etc) - it makes the pattern easier to read, the intent is clearer.

Comment: capturing groups in a test regex are irrelevant

Comment: @ic3b3rg If you're reading some code and you're 100% sure in advance that a pattern is going to be used for `.test` and nothing else, sure - but that's often not the case, and I think there are benefits a consistent style with the least cognitive overhead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the use case here is clearly for validation - the non-capturing groups only add unnecessary complexity

Comment: Sounds like you're not ready to embrace "least cognitive overhead" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for repeating patterns of `\w+\.` after the @, i.e.

```js
const tests = [
  'aaa@.xyz.com',
  'aaa@a.xyz.com',
  'aaa@a..xyz.com',
  'aaa@some.xx.com'
]

tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log(test, /^([a-z]{3,})+@(\w+\.)+(com|org)$/i.test(test));
});
```